# Is mocking filesystem necessary?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have written some business logic for operating on files and I needed to write some integration tests to check whether everything works OK. Because I was short on time I have written simply `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods which created files and deleted them after tests (I couldn't have used streams because part of functionality was to delete files). Right now I have a bit more time so I am wondering if my solution was that bad because of no mocking? If so, should I have used some implementation of `java.nio.file.FileSystem` or maybe `TemporaryFolder` from JUnit would be enough for it to be considered proper test?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on whether the files creation and removal is part of logic that needs to be tested, or just a side-effect of the functionality.**

1. if it is part of the functionality, it should be mocked out and Java 7's NIO and `java.nio.file.FileSystem` is the way to go
2. if it is just a side-effect, then `TemporaryFolder` or similar functionality is fine

Comment: So Just to be sure: if I'm using external library for those operations it's classified as the second variant?

Comment: Absolutely. Unit test should mock out all the test collaborators and you don't want to test external library. So in your case it is a side-effect and then the verification should not be part of the test.